# the res.write in express displays the HTML element inside of it

Tags: javascript, express

I am not to web app dev and I started using express and I have this code

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  var crypto = req.body.crypto;
  var fiat = req.body.fiat;
  var amount = req.body.amount;

  var options = {
    url: "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/convert/global",
    method: "GET",
    qs: {
      from: crypto,
      to: fiat,
      amount: amount
    }
  };
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var time = data.time;
    var price = data.price;
    res.write("Current time is: " + time);
    res.write("<p> Your " + amount + " " + crypto + " is worth " + price + 
    " " + fiat + "</p>");
    res.send();
  });
});
```

But when I run my server and and run the POST request what is displayed on the page looks like this:

Current time is: 2019-06-29 18:50:35 `<p>` Your 2 BTC is worth 23954.24 USD`</p>`

From what I know res.write() isn't supposed to render the HTML and not show the HTML elements as text.

Am I doing something wrong here?? How can I fix it so the HTML tags don't show up in the page as text?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below codes before this line:

> res.write("Current time is: " + time);

- `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})`
- `res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html')`
- `res.type('text/html')`

After this, try clearing cache too if it doesn't help.

That's actually just vanilla nodejs. Read more here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

Comment: Didn't work still when I run the server I get the HTML tags appear as a string
Current time is: 2019-06-29 18:50:35 <p>Your 2 BTC is worth 23954.24 USD</p>

Comment: Tried it and I got the following error

_http_outgoing.js:470    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');    ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\Learning\Web development bootcamp\APIs\bitcoin-ticker\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)    at Request._callback (F:\Learning\Web development bootcamp\APIs\bitcoin-ticker\index.js:31:9)

Comment: Don't put them all in there, just try one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.write("<html><p> Your " + amount + " " + crypto + " is worth " + price + 
" " + fiat + "</p></html>");
```

this should fix it.
adding html tags around the paragraph tags should work.